# Replacing a word with another in a string if a condition is met

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to get some help with a function on replacing two words in a string with another word if a condition is `true`. 
The condition is: if the word '`poor`' follows '`not`', then replace the whole string '`not ... poor`' with '`rich`'. The problem is that I don't know how to make the function - more specific how to make a function that seeks for if the word poor follows not and then what I have to write to make the replacement. I am pretty new to python, so maybe it is a stupid questions but i hope someone will help me.

I want the function to do something like this:

```
string = 'I am not that poor' 

new_string = 'I am rich'
```

Comment: Did you even bother to read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace)

Comment: I did, but the problem is that i can't figure out how to make the if statement for the condition - if the word 'not' is placed before 'poor' in the string, then replace the part from 'not' to 'poor' with 'rich. I know how to replace in a string, but not how to write a function that does it when condition is true or if it is possible to make one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doubtless the regular expression pattern could be improved, but a quick and dirty way to do this is with Python's `re` module:

```
import re
patt = 'not\s+(.+\s)?poor'
s = 'I am not that poor'
sub_s = re.sub(patt, 'rich', s)
print s, '->', sub_s
s2 = 'I am not poor'
sub_s2 = re.sub(patt, 'rich', s2)
print s2, '->', sub_s2
s3 = 'I am poor not'
sub_s3 = re.sub(patt, 'rich', s3)
print s3, '->', sub_s3
```

Output:

```
I am not that poor -> I am rich
I am not poor -> I am rich
I am poor not -> I am poor not
```

The regular expression pattern `patt` matches the text `not` followed by a space and (optionally) other characters followed by a space and then the word `poor`.

Comment: thanks. I have tried to do it, but it doesn't print anything out for me. I have try to put it into a function - 
def not_poor(s):
    import re
    patt = 'not\s[.+\s]?poor'
    if patt in s:
        print re.sub(patt, 'rich', s)

But nothing comes out. I can't really see what i am doing wrong.

Comment: I've turned it into a script for you -- perhaps you weren' `print`ing the results of the `re.sub` call?

Comment: I think I didn't make myself clear in my question, sorry. The function has to make the replacement if 'not' is before 'poor' in the string, and not if 'poor' follows 'not'. So "I am not that poor" should change to "I am rich", while a string like "I am that poor not" would be the same. Sorry for that. I don't know if it is possible to make a function that would make a replacement like that.

Comment: My bad: wrong sort of brackets. I've corrected my answer: I think it does what you want now.

Answer (score 0):

Step One:  Determine where the 'not' and 'poor' are inside your string (check out https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)

Step Two:  Compare the locations of 'not' and 'poor' that you just found.  Does 'poor' come after 'not'?  How could you tell?  Are there any extra edge cases you should account for?

Step Three:  If your conditions are not met, do nothing.  If they are, everything between and including 'not' and 'poor' must be replaced by 'rich'.  I'll leave you to decide how to do that, given the above documentation link.

Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. Sorry, but I still don't quite get it. I know(or think) that I have to use at least two string type methods: str.find on the first one, and str.replace on the last one. But I think I should make a if statement in my function aswell. Is that wrong? And I still can't see, how I write in my function the comparison of the locations of the words into a function that does something if the condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I came up with. Works for your example, but will need tweaks (what if there is more than 1 word between not and poor).

```
my_string = 'I am not that poor'
print my_string
my_list = my_string.split(' ')

poor_pos = my_list.index('poor')
if my_list[poor_pos - 1] or my_list[poor_pos - 2] == 'not':
    not_pos = my_list.index('not')
    del my_list[not_pos:poor_pos+1]
    my_list.append('rich')

print " ".join(word for word in my_list)
```

Output:

```
I am not that poor
I am rich
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but xnx had the answer I was looking for (: